# o.s.cloud.stream.binding.Binding Service : Failed to create producer binding

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I am trying build spring config client in clustered env, for this to achieve I am using `kafka` to connect between clients. My client project works with local `kafka` server but when I try to connect to my remote `kafka` server application do not start up and throw me with below errors,

```
2019-01-09 00:06:00.364  INFO 17892 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2019-01-09 00:06:00.364  INFO 17892 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2019-01-09 00:08:00.369  INFO 17892 --- [thread | client] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=client] Metadata update failed

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.

2019-01-09 00:10:00.366  INFO 17892 --- [thread | client] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=client] Metadata update failed

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.

2019-01-09 00:10:00.371 ERROR 17892 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: Provisioning exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

in `pom.xml`,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Im also facing the same issue when deployed in Google kubernetes engine.But kafka communication works fine in local using sping boot.